# strange illegalArgumentException rooted from JBoss 5.0.1 GA

Tags: jakarta-ee, web, jboss

We have a java web application that is deployed to JBoss 5.0.1 GA. Sometimes, we observe such exceptions from our server log

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at java.nio.Buffer.position(Buffer.java:216)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter.convert(B2CConverter.java:84)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.realReadChars(InputBuffer.java:403)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.CharChunk.substract(CharChunk.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:432)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader.read(CoyoteReader.java:105)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteReader.readLine(CoyoteReader.java:158)
```

....

The code from our part that triggered the exception is

```
public static String getStringFromRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String data = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        // the line below is the the line that blows the exception
        String line = reader.readLine();

        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        reader.close();
        data = sb.toString();
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
         ...
     }
     return data;
}
```

We have never seen this exception in our testing env. Only in production, when traffic is definitely heavier. Has anyone seen this before? It would be very helpful if we know what could trigger the exception so we know how to reproduce and fix it. Any hints/helps is deeply appreciated

Answer (score 0):

A posible solution to the issue is to upgrade your `jbossweb.jar`.

According to the jira issue, the fix has been committed to the `2.x branch`:   [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException on JBoss 5.0.1](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-7817)

Possible workaround ([java.lang.IllegalArgumentException  on JBOSS](https://developer.jboss.org/message/531900#531900)):

> The following steps helped solve similar issues we had on servers with
>   `jboss-5.1.0.GA`. (taking into account you have a development
>   environment with eclipse and ant) :
>
> 1. checkout a snapshot which includes the above fix of the jbossweb project from the anon svn:
>
>    - http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/jbossweb/tags/JBOSSWEB_2_1_9_GA/
> 2. apply the attached patch so a `jbossweb.jar` can be generated (I just commented extra unnecessary resource downloads and compilations).
>
>    - **NOTE:** I used eclipse helios to build the jar, so just update the `jdt.home` and 
>        `jdt.jar properties` in build.properties.default to match the locations of your eclipse and jdt jar locations.
> 3. run the ant deploy target.
> 4. if your build is successful, a new jbossweb.jar with the fix will be generated under `output/jars/jbossweb.jar`.
> 5. copy the new `jbossweb.jar` over the old `<profile>/deploy/jbossweb.sar/jbossweb.jar`
> 6. restart jboss.

I hope this help.

Comment: Thank you very much, Federico. Really appreciate it. Do you happen to know how to reproduce the error, i.e, under what circumstances would JBoss spit that error? I want to know that so I can tell for sure that the thing is fixed or I would have to cross the fingers for a long time to make sure it does not appear again